# Command migrate uninstallation

Tags: migrate, linuxbrew

I have installed migrate using linuxbrew. now I wants to remove the installation. What is the command for it?.

which migrate:

/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/migrate

I have to remove the above migrate.

Comment: This is off-topic and should be on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) :)

Comment: it is solved  using brew uninstall migrate

Comment: If you find how to fix your issue you can self-answer !